# Cannot use both headphone ports on Dell XPS L502X at the same time

Tags: sound, hardware, dell

I am having a problem in Ubuntu 11.10 using both of the headphone ports on my Dell.

This may or may not apply to other computers as well.

Basically, there is a normal headphone jack next to an S/PDIF jack next to a mic jack.

Unfortunately, I am unable to use both headphone jacks simultaneously, as is possible when running Windows.

How can Ubuntu be reconfigured so as to use both headphone jacks?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: @BlueXrider I'm still here.... this is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9184185&postcount=3).
Its a link to an ubuntu forums post giving the solution to a similar problem.

EDIT:

Though I would recommend going through the links to solve the problem but as the person below asked me to put the instructions in the post itself, so here we go:

Find your sound card model using this:

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
```

For me this outputs:

```
Codec: IDT 92HD73C1X5
```

The file /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz lists the sound card models with available modprobe modules to use.

```
zless /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz
```

The full model number wasn't in there, because the model has been wildcarded. I searched for:

```
92HD73
```

Now put:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-eq
```

or:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6
```

into the file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Now which line to put in the file will depend on the model of your laptop. In short, its the former line to put for dell studio 15xx models and latter for studio 17xx as indicated in this thread on [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1469949%22on%20ubuntu%20forums%22)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.